# MVC4 Creating Register pages using one Model

Tags: ajax, database, asp.net-mvc-4, model

I don't really have a good example for this mostly because I'm just winging it and so far, my code is just a jumbled up mish-mash of gobble-dee-gook. I'm at a loss and need some help or advice on this one. Here's what I need:

I am creating a mock *register form* meant for learning purposes only. I used a *job application form* as my example. One page has the applicant's personal info such as first and last name, age, gender, and level of education. The second page allows them to choose which position they wish to apply for and allows them to provide a list of skills. I have a single `model` set up to take the `data` and `save` it to a `database`. The first page will have an `ajax` *next button* that replaces the first page form with the second page form. The second page has two buttons, *Back* and *Submit* (simple enough) that are also `ajax-y`. My issue right now is getting the `data` from both forms to save to a single `entry` in the `model`. Does anyone have a simple example or a link I could look into for this kind of situation? Or maybe even another way of going about this? It would be greatly appreciated!! :)

**Model**

```
public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First name Req")]
    [Display(Name = "First name")]
    public string First { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last name Req")]
    [Display(Name = "Last name")]
    public string Last { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Age Req")]
    [Range(18, 75, ErrorMessage = "Age Range of {1}-{2}")]
    public int Age { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Select Gender")]
    public string Gender { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Education Level Req")]
    public string Education { get; set; }

    public string Position { get; set; }

    public string Skills { get; set; }
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
    public PartialViewResult Apply1()
    {
        var model = db.Applications.Find(id);
        if (model != null)
        {
            return PartialView("_Apply1", model);
        }
        return PartialView("_Apply1");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult Apply1(Application app)
    {
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            if (db.Applications.Where(a => a.First.ToLower() == app.First.ToLower() && a.Last.ToLower() == app.Last.ToLower() && a.Age == app.Age && a.Gender == app.Gender && a.Education == app.Education).Count() == 0)
            {
                app.Position = "x";
                db.Applications.Add(app);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            else
            {
                app = db.Applications.Single(a => a.First.ToLower() == app.First.ToLower() && a.Last.ToLower() == app.Last.ToLower() && a.Age == app.Age && a.Gender == app.Gender && a.Education == app.Education);
            }

            PosList(); //This is a helper Method, get's values for a dropdown list
            id = app.Id;
            var model = db.Applications.Find(id);
            return PartialView("_Apply2", model);
        }

        return PartialView("_Apply1", app);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public PartialViewResult Apply2()
    {
        var model = db.Applications.Find(id);
        if (model != null)
        {
            return PartialView("_Apply2", model);
        }
        return PartialView("_Apply2");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult Apply2(Application app)
    {


        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(app).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            ModelState.Clear();
            return PartialView("_Success");
        }

        PosList();
        return PartialView("_Apply2", app);
    }
```

**First View**

```
@model SiPrac.Models.Application

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Apply1", new AjaxOptions()
{
InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
UpdateTargetId = "appForm"
}))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.First)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.First)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.First)
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Last)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Last)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Last)
</div>
<div class="clear">

<input class="btn" type="submit" value="Next" />
}
```

**Second View**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Apply2", new AjaxOptions()
{
InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
UpdateTargetId = "appForm"
}))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Position)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Position, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["selectPos"])
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<input class="btn" type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Comment: Show what you have, you can include one field from each form so you don't have to post a lot of codes in your question. Also, post the model that you have. But basically you can pass the inputs into the model via ajax.

Comment: What I have so far has been added.

Comment: You said you wanted to pass all the fields from the two forms but you are showing two post methods here. So do you intend to pass all the fields from the two forms on each of those post methods - doesn't make sense though?

Comment: I honestly couldn't tell you. I've just been winging this since I can't find a good explanation on how to do this. Should I do it a completely different way? Could you post an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I'll try to make this as short as possible. So assuming you already know how to switch between forms, as I know you do based on your question, and you have forms like these:

```
<form id="form1">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.First)
    // rest of the fields goes here
</form>
<form id="form2">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Position)
    // rest of the fields goes here
    <button id="submitAll">Submit</button>
</form>
```

That assumes that you have the buttons to switch back and forth the views. The `submitAll` button triggers the postback action to a controller method and pass the value like this:

```
function submitAllFields() {
    var o = {
        // list properties here similar to your model property name
        // and assign values to them
        First: $("#First").val(),
        Position: $("#Position").val()
    };
    $.post('@Url.Action("apply2")', { app: o }, function(result) {
        // do something here
    });
}
```

You then need one method to accept **all** the inputs:

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult Apply2(Application app)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(app).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        ModelState.Clear();
        return PartialView("_Success");
    }
    // do something here
}
```

Comment: So, quick question, in the example you provided, the forms are on separate views, right? I'm not sure if that's how I should set them up, I just assumed since they are on separate pages.

Comment: They don't need to be especially if you don't have hundred of fields.

Comment: I'm sorry but that was the whole point of my exercise. Having two different forms on a single page is easy enough, that I know how to work with. But that's not what's going on here. I know I don't have a bunch of fields at the moment but I need to be able to learn how to save all the data from two separate forms that are on two separate pages into a single database entry. The model holds the list of those fields that are to be filled out by the user. I'm terribly sorry if I didn't explain that well enough in my introduction paragraph. D:

Comment: Well that's a suggestion but you can have them on separate pages that in the end, they all will end up in one html page. You mentioned you call the pages via ajax, so when you do that, just hide the previous form that were shown. IN that manner you won't lose your inputs. If you prefer to save your input fields from each form because you want to totally erase "the previous form" when loading a new one then that needs a longer client-side code.

Comment: Fair enough. I just really wanted to know if that way I was aiming to do it was possible or not. From what I've been doing so far, it isn't because of validation and model issues. Guess I'll just to it the ajax-y, all on one page, two separate forms, show/hide, blah blah blah way. XDD Sorry if I wasted your time but thanks you for clearing a lot of things up for me~ :) I really appreciate the help!

Comment: "Sorry if I wasted your time" - not at all and I'm glad to have cleared up some things for you. There's really a few ways you can achieve what you want. The best thing is you tried them all and see (or feel) what fits your scenario best.

Comment: yeah, that's true~ :D It took me a while to even get it the way suggested but I finally got it. I'm debating whether I should post my new code or not. O.o?